# MediaController / VideoView can't play mp4 on certain phones

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-videoview, mediacontroller

From within my app I create a video from images that the user has taken using Ffmpeg. I the play this using MediaController and a VideoView. When I run the app using the Genymotion emulator for a Google Nexus 4 the video file plays without issue. When I use the Genymotion emulator for a Samsung Galaxy S4 I get an error from the VideoView on error listener say "Can't play video".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Showing your actual `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output will be informative.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the video using `ffmpeg` worked fine for my application. I hope this helps:

```
ffmpeg -i old.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 1 -strict -2 new.mp4
```

I found this line of code somewhere else on Stack Overflow but I could not retrace where, unfortunately. So, in case someone comes across it, please link it here. The original one did not have the `-strict -2` in the command.

Answer (score -1):

Simply because the extension is `.mp4` cannot guarantee it will be played by the MediaPlayer. If its not a supported encoding it wont play it. Please do have a look at all the [supported media formats in Android here.](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

So introspect your code and find the type of encoding your video uses. Also if you are looking more an even powerful way to play video, you can also try out Google's Exoplayer, [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).

Comment: Hi @oblivion, Yeah I have checked that link out before posting and everything should be fine according to the prescribed codecs. I will check out Exoplayer thanks.

Comment: And, always test the app on real device to confirm something! Happy coding :)